# IllegalArgumentException("Null KeyStore name") while trying to debug SpringBoot App

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging

I`ve got IllegalArgumentException("Null KeyStore name") in PolicyUtil.java while trying to debug SpringBoot App. Debugging in every other project, including SpringBoot projects, works fine. I tried to change Java version - tried 11, 17 but it was useless.

[KeyStore details empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k08aD.png)
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 10):

It's because you have an exception breakpoint configured. You've to click on the little storm on the sidebar to remove it and it'll work.